# How to find the options in R CMD?

Tags: r

I'd generate a pdf from Rd file use:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf [options] files
```

I'm wondering how to show up the available `options` in this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf --help
```